# How to find a record using dot notation & update the value in a schema using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean.io

I am using mongoose to perform CRUD operation on my db. This is how my model looks.

```
var EmployeeSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  description: {
    type: String,
    default: 'No description'
  },
 department: [],
  lastUpdated: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }

});
```

The department can contains array of object like this.

```
[
      {
            "id" : "55ba28f680dec4383eeebf97",
            "text" : "Sales",
            "topParentId" : "55ba28f680dec4383eeebf8b",
            "topParentText" : "XYZ"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "55ba28f680dec4383eeebf98",
            "text" : "IT",
            "topParentId" : "55ba28f680dec4383eeebf8b",
            "topParentText" : "XYZ"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "55ba28f680dec4383eeebf94",
            "text" : "Marketing",
            "topParentId" : "55ba28f680dec4383eeebccc",
            "topParentText" : "ABC"
        }
]
```

Now I need to find all the employee where department.id = '55ba28f680dec4383eeebf94' and then I need to update the text of the object.

```
Employee.find({'department.id': '55ba28f680dec4383eeebf94'}, function(err, Employees) {      
    _.each(Employees, function (emp) {    
      _.each(emp.department, function (dept) {
        if(dept.id === '55ba28f680dec4383eeebf94'){
          dept.text = 'XXXXX'; // How to update the employee to save the updated text
        }
      });

    });

  });
```

**What is the right way to save the employee with updated text for that department?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterating is code is not a "sharp" way to do this. It is better to use the MongoDB update operators, especially since there is no schema defined for the array items here, so no rules to worry about:

```
Employee.update(
    {'department.id': '55ba28f680dec4383eeebf94'},
    { "$set": { "department.$.text": "XXXXX" },
    function(err,numAffected) {
       // handling in here
    }
);
```

The [**`$set`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) is the important part, otherwise you overwrite the whole object. As is the [positional `$` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) in the statement, so only the matched ( queried item in the array ) index is updated.

Also see [`.find**AndUpdate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate) variants for a way to return the modified object.

Comment: I am also using `{multi: true}` option to update every record that I find.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use the `update` model:

```
Employee.update({department.id: '55ba28f680dec4383eeebf94'}, {department.text: 'XXXXX'}, {multi: true}, 
    function(err, num) {
        console.log("updated "+num);
    }
);
```

First object is the query, what to find: `{department.id: '55ba28f680dec4383eeebf94'}`, the second one is the update, what to update: `{department.text: 'XXXXX'}` and the third one is the options to pass to the update, `multi` means update every records you find: `{multi: true}`

Comment: Some how this is not working for me. I have am using Blakes Seven answer and using `{multi: true}` from your answer. Voting up for that option. Thanks